# Configure MySQL in SublimeText 3

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, sublimetext3

I want to configure MySQL in SublimeText 3, I found that the configuration is from Build System / New Build System ...

My written code is as follows:

```
{
"cmd": ["C: /xampp/mysql/bin/mysql.exe", "-u", "dorbezo", "-P", "Dorbezo123", "-h", "192.168.1.99", " -e "," source $ file "," -t "],
"selector": "source.sql",
"quiet": true}
```

My credentials to access MySQL from Workbench are the following:

user: dorbezo,
pass: Dorbezo123,
host: port: 192.168.1.99:3306

Am I entering the connection correctly? It is worth mentioning that I connect via VPN and I have ** xampp ** started when I try to run a query, getting the following error:

** show databases; **
Unknown suffix 'D' used for variable 'port' (value 'Dorbezo123')
C: /xampp/mysql/bin/mysql.exe: Error while setting value 'Dorbezo123' to 'port'

I also mention that the port where ** xampp ** connects is 3307, since 3306 (which I use in Workbench) causes me conflict.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212363/79040) by `Jenny D` to the question *Hiding Passwords in Shell Scripts* has superb advice about password security. I recommend you read it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your `.sublime-build` file.

- Your command path `"C: /xampp/mysql/bin/mysql.exe"` has a space in it but perhaps that was pasted into your post incorrectly. I would have expected something more like this on Windows: `"C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysql.exe"`.
- You are using an uppercase `-P` for your password, it should be a lowercase `-p`.
- You possibly need to add the port number with the uppercase `"-P", "3306"`. I say 'possibly' because 3306 is the default port for MySQL so you may not need to specify it at all.
- Using [long form options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html) is generally a good idea because they prevent letter case mistakes. e.g. `--user, --password, --host, --port, --execute, --table`.

Here is a `MySQL.sublime-build` file for you to try, the long options (with my details) work for me on Linux:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysql.exe", "--user=dorbezo", "--password=Dorbezo123", "--host=192.168.1.99", "--port=3306", "--execute=source $file", "--table"],
    "selector": "source.sql"
}
```

Clearly storing a password in a `.sublime-build` file is a security risk. You should consider creating a MySQL user with an insecure password which has limited privileges.

There is also the [SQLTools Sublime Text plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SQLTools) which you could install, [see here for the documentation](https://code.mteixeira.dev/SublimeText-SQLTools/). Instead of your connection details being stored in a `.sublime-build` file you would add them in a `SQLToolsConnections.sublime-settings` settings file. The documentation link above has detailed examples. I suspect you might find using this plugin easier than managing the build file. Using this plugin means there is less of a password security issue; if you use `null` in the password field (not in quotes) then the plugin will prompt for the password and then remember it for the session (I think).